# Dropping rows in a certain time interval

Tags: python, pandas, time, intervals, drop

So we have a Pandas DataFrame with certain values at certain times.

For example:

```
    @ts               @value Glucose Diff   smooth_diff new P          N    C1  C2

135 2021-10-29 11:16:00 167  167.0  -3.0    15.45   15.45   17.95   17.45   NaN 0.0
155 2021-10-29 12:56:00 162  162.0  -15.0   15.35   15.35   17.95   16.00   NaN 0.0
243 2021-10-29 20:16:00 133  133.0  0.0     15.25   15.25   19.85   15.75   NaN 0.0
245 2021-10-29 20:26:00 134  134.0  0.0     15.50   15.50   15.75   15.60   NaN 0.0
113 2021-10-29 09:26:00 130  130.0  1.0     16.75   16.75   0.00    21.70   NaN NaN
```

Now we want to drop the rows that are in an 1 hour time interval (the @ts column) of each other (so in this example we want to drop the row at 2021-10-29 20:26:00 as it is within an 1 hour time span of the previous one), but we can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

Any help?

Comment: We believe we have to use a for loop but aren't sure how to implement this

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe (only creating 2 cols for ease)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '@ts': ['2021-10-29 11:16:00', '2021-10-29 12:56:00', '2021-10-29 20:16:00', 
            '2021-10-29 20:26:00'],
    '@value': [167, 162, 133, 134]
})

# split @ts column into separate columns - date(d) and time(t)
df[["d", "t"]] = df["@ts"].str.split(" ", expand=True)

# split time column into separate parts, hours, mins and secs
df[["h", "m", "s"]] = df["t"].str.split(":", expand=True)
# drop duplicates based on date and hour, keep the first row
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["d", "h"], keep="first")
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the column to `datetime`. Subtract the `time` with the previous row `time` and then evaluate the `total seconds`. Calculate the `abs` value and check if it's greater than `3600` or not to create a boolean mask.
Then, use the boolean mask to filter the required rows.

```
df['@ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['@ts'])
df = df[~(df['@ts'] - df['@ts'].shift()
          ).dt.total_seconds().fillna(np.inf).apply(abs).lt(3600)]
```